# .htaccess URL rewrite returns 1 digit of ID / Simple Test

Tags: php, .htaccess

Url rewrite returns only the first digit of the ID on the below sample

Test Html below

```
<h1> Hello Test</h1>
<br>
<?php
    $i=1;
    while($i<=15){
        $j=99;
        echo "<a href=\"user.php?id=$i&uid=$j\"> User ".$i ."</a><br>";
        $i++;
        }
?>
```

My php file

```
<?php 
    if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
        header('location:test.php');
        }
    else if (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['uid'])){
        echo "User ID : ". $_GET['id'] . "<br>";
        echo "My ID : ". $_GET['uid'] . "<br>";
        }
?>
```

and my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^test?$ test.php

RewriteRule ^user/([0-9}+])/([0-9}+]) user.php?id=$1&uid=$2
```

The result in

http://....user/8/99 is

User ID : 8

My ID : 9 <---- it should be 99. The second 9 is missing and the same happens with the User ID.

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved, there was a typing error in the last rule

```
Wrong : RewriteRule ^user/([0-9}+])/([0-9}+]) user.php?id=$1&uid=$2

Right : RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) user.php?id=$1&uid=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

`[0-9]+`
This means: One or more (+) of a set ([...]) of digits (0-9).